# Angular 6 - Change header / footer after login

Tags: angular

I can't seem to find good documentation on how to swap the header and footer components in an Angular 6 application.

My app.component.html file looks like:

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

What I need to do is have app nav and app footer change to a different component / template when logged in.  What is the best approach for this?

Comment: You can keep the loggedIn information in a common shared service , which can reuse in all the components you need to control the visibility based on the logged in status(using ngIf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make use of `*ngIf`:

```
<app-nav *ngIf="loggedIn"></app-nav>
<app-nav-unlogged *ngIf="!loggedIn"></app-nav-unlogged>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="loggedIn"></app-footer>
<app-footer-unlogged *ngIf="!loggedIn"></app-footer-unlogged>
```

where `loggedIn` is a boolean defined in your component (can also have `*ngIf="user"` / `*ngIf="!user"`, `user` being an object that's null when unlogged).

Comment: I needed to introduce a few more things like an isPublicRoute route data element to my routes and a subscription to my auth store in the component, but it's all working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its a best way, but you can make use of 'if-else' in the footer template attaching that with the log in.